# Error while indexing in Hibernate Search (before transaction completion)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, transactions, spring-batch, hibernate-search

I am tired of banging my head around this problem So if anyone could suggest me where I am wrong I'll be grateful.

The problem is I am using [Spring-Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/) and [Hibernate Full-Text Search](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html) in my  Spring MVC project.So from the batch job Tasklet I am calling following code:

```
 A a=aDao.merge(a);
 b.setA(a);
 bDao.save(b);
```

While doing the save update on these entites I am getting an exception and the stacktrace is as follows:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Error while indexing in Hibernate Search (before transaction completion); nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error while indexing in Hibernate Search (before transaction completion)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:690)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:793)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:664)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:147)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:264)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:250)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error while indexing in Hibernate Search (before transaction completion)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.EventSourceTransactionContext$DelegateToSynchronizationOnBeforeTx.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(EventSourceTransactionContext.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:543)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:571)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.beforeTransactionCompletion(JDBCContext.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:138)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.search.util.HibernateHelper.unproxy(HibernateHelper.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFields(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:394)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFields(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:481)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFields(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:481)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.getDocument(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.createAddWork(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.addWorkToQueue(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.WorkPlan$PerEntityWork.enqueueLuceneWork(WorkPlan.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.WorkPlan$PerClassWork.enqueueLuceneWork(WorkPlan.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.WorkPlan.getPlannedLuceneWork(WorkPlan.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.WorkQueue.prepareWorkPlan(WorkQueue.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.BatchedQueueingProcessor.prepareWorks(BatchedQueueingProcessor.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.beforeCompletion(PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.EventSourceTransactionContext$DelegateToSynchronizationOnBeforeTx.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(EventSourceTransactionContext.java:172)
    ... 27 more
```

I am not getting whats gone wrong.I am using `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager` and my Spring version is 3.2 Hibernate core version is 3.6 final.

Note :This exception occurs often but When I create a new tables or use fresh db it works like charm and all modification/insertion are getting reflected properly in database.Can somebody explain me this behavior or Have i done something fishy.

Tell me if you need more details.

Thank you.

**Code Update:**

```
<batch:job-repository id="jobRepository"
                          data-source="myJNDI"
                          transaction-manager="transactionManager"
                          isolation-level-for-create="READ_COMMITTED"
                          max-varchar-length="2500"
                          lob-handler="defaultLobHandler"
    />



  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="safeSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Like this I am configuring transaction manager in applicationContext.xml for Spring-Batch.And I have tried doing this with manually opening and closing session with manual commit of transaction but the exception remains same.And yes I have annotated my method as @Transactional.

Comment: The reason for the exception is that when the indexing (creating of Lucene document) occurs your session is already closed. Given that your associations are lazy an open session (transaction) is needed to successfully index. Your code examples do not show how you manage transactions. Can you show some example code? Are you using @Transactional or are you using the open session in view pattern (meaning a transaction is open during the full http request)?

Comment: @Hardy details updated as you asked.And one more thing Spring batch is background process so it doesn't fall under Single HttpRequest category so I think OpenSessionInView Pattern not gonna affect it.Plz correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I am not a Spring expert, so I was not aware of Spring Batch. You are probably right that the OpenSessionInView pattern does not work in this case. Nevertheless, the problem is that the current session is closed when indexing happens. Where in your code does the Session get opened/closed? In the DAO? Do you do that explicitly? You might want to enable debug trace and follow the chain of events. You should be able to see the opening/closing of the session being logged as well as the indexing work. An alternative for you might be to index programatically instead of relying on automatic indexing.

Comment: @Hardy K I'll try as you suggested and get back to you if i get something strange.Thanks.

Comment: @DanglingPiyush if u find any solution related to your question please post it as a answer, it will be very helpful for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause of problem is [Spring's Declarative Transaction Management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative).
Spring Batch in Action Reference:

> - Disable Spring’s declarative transactions for your batch application—Don’t use the tx:annotation-driven element or any XML
>     configuration related to declara- tive transaction management.
> - Be careful using propagation levels if declarative transactions are on—If you call trans- actional classes from a Spring Batch job,
>     Spring’s transaction propagation can interfere with the Spring Batch
>     transaction because of the propagation level. The REQUIRES_NEW
>     propagation level could typically cause problems because the
>     application code runs in its own transaction, independent of the
>     Spring Batch transaction.

The following are guidelines to avoid conflict between Spring Batch–managed and
Spring-managed transactions:

[image: Transaction Diagram]